# C++ WINAPI Hidden radiobutton isnt unchecking

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have 2 radiobuttons in a Win32 application.
Imagine this scenario:
I am checking button number one and hiding it immediately with this code:

`ShowWindow(RadioButtonTwo, SW_HIDE);`

I am now checking button number two and hiding it immediately too.
Now I am unhiding number one, but its still checked. How to solve this?

Comment: It matters whether the button has the BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON style turned on and lives with its siblings inside a group box, details that are unclear from your question.  Hiding a radio button when there are only two makes little sense, you should be using a static control instead.

Comment: I dont have only two controls, i have a groupbox where 2 radiobuttons are fitting, and im hiding the other two ones (number 3 is placed at the pos. of number one, number four at the pos. of number two). If i press the button i am hiding one and two and showing three and four.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`BM_SETCHECK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb775989.aspx) message to send a message to the window with the `RadioButtonOne` handle, with the `BST_UNCHECKED` state as follows:

```
::SendMessage( RadioButtonOne, BM_SETCHECK, BST_UNCHECKED, NULL );
```

Or alternatively if you have a `CButton` MFC class you can use the [`SetCheck`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31deb72x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function with `BST_UNCHECKED` as a parameter:

```
CButton btnTest;
btnTest.SetCheck( BST_UNCHECKED );
```

Comment: That was not for what I was asking for... I already tried that way, but I only want to uncheck it when i hit number 2, and hidden radiobuttons arent responding on BM_GETCHECK so i can only send BM_SETCHECK randomly without knowing that number one is checked.